# How to pass X-Auth-Token in the HTTP header in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, token, xauth

I have a website which uses Token-based authentication. At first, username and password are sent to log the user in and receive the token. For subsequent calls, I need to include the token as `X-Auth-Token` in HTTP header.

I would like to know how to do that, in vanilla JavaScript or using jQuery. Could you please provide me a sample of code?

Comment: are you using ajax, if yes can you share your code

Comment: Read this http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method

Comment: I can use ajax in the app

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In jQuery it would be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url : myurl,
   headers: {
        'X-Auth-Token' : token
   });
```

More details on what you can do with `$.ajax()` are in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)